# How can I get Rails to interpret a text field as a datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, strtotime

My database has a datetime field, and I want to be able to create new entries. Obviously the [Rails datetime_select helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M001700) isn't the most user friendly thing to have in your form.

I'd rather have a text field for the datetime (or one for the date, and one for the time) and interpret the inputs like [PHP strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can.

I might just be searching the wrong keywords. Surely this has been discussed in great depth somewhere.

Thanks

:0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Railscast #32](http://railscasts.com/episodes/32-time-in-text-field), I've used this method a few times and it works pretty well.